# Scraping dynamic web page with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the links of the posts on this page, but they are apparently generated by clicking each of the post images. I'm using Selenium and beautifulsoup4 in Python 3.8.
Any idea how to get the links while selenium continues to the next pages?

[image: HTML Code]

url: [https://www.goplaceit.com/cl/mapa?id_modalidad=1&tipo_pro//*[@id=%22gpi-property-list-container%22]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/imgpiedad=1%2C2&selectedTool=list#12/-33.45/-70.66667](https://www.goplaceit.com/cl/mapa?id_modalidad=1&tipo_pro//*%5B@id=%22gpi-property-list-container%22%5D/div%5B3%5D/div%5B1%5D/div%5B1%5D/imgpiedad=1%2C2&selectedTool=list#12/-33.45/-70.66667)

after clicking on the image it opens a new tab with the following type of shortening url: https://www.goplaceit.com/propiedad/6198212

which sends me to a url type:

https://www.goplaceit.com/cl/propiedad/venta/departamento/santiago/6198212-depto-con-1d-1b-y-terraza-a-pasos-del-metro-toesca-bodega

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import winsound
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
start = timer()

PROXY = "PROXY" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
path_to_extension = r"extension"
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_extension)
#options.add_argument('--disable-java')
options.headless = False
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
prefs2 = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
prefs.update(prefs2)
prefs3 = {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2}
prefs.update(prefs3)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.goplaceit.com/cl/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/nav/div/div[2]/div[1]/button'))).click()
correo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')
correo.send_keys("Mail")
contraseña = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')
contraseña.send_keys("password")
contraseña.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(7)


elem.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gpi-main-landing-search-input"]/div/input')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("keywords")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gpi-main-landing-search-input"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/div/div[1]'))).click()
buscador.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="custom-checkbox"]'))).click()

page_number = 0
max_page_number = 30
while page_number<=max_page_number:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"paginator-btn-right")]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get easily the urls by clicking on an image, saving your url, coming back to the first page and repeating this for all the images:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver.get("https://www.goplaceit.com/cl/mapa?id_modalidad=1&tipo_propiedad=1%2C2&selectedTool=list#8/-33.958/-71.206")
images = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-iyvyFf ljSqTz']//img")))
urls = []
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    image.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    window_after = driver.window_handles[i+1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
    urls.append(driver.current_url)
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. I change the dynamic Xpath to a fixed one: ```images = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gpi-property-list-container"]//img')))```, but it only gives me the links of the images, and what I need are the links that the page opens when clicking on each of the images

Comment: oh sorry, it wasn't very clear! I just edited the answer for your case, now you will get the urls of the pages that you open by clicking on images

Comment: searching I found the same, but I appreciate your answer!